# MS Access - Automatically calculate & display the value to textbox based on selection of two comboboxes

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to Access, just try to build a database for input orders,
I would like to make a form to input orders with some auto calculation,
it seems easy, but I fail to make it, pls help! XP

Just want to auto calculate the commission in frmOrder by searching the related "CommRate" (based on "SalesID" & "ProductID") x "Quantity" and return value to commission field.

[My file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=54223985791243350598&t=5422398579124335059848679)

Comment: You should look up and study some tutorials on getting started with Microsoft Access. Also, please have in mind that SO is a code helping, not an application writing, forum.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use dLookup for this.  Something like:

```
MyVar = dLookup("CommRate", "tblComm", "SalesID = '" & Me.txtSalesID & "' and 
ProductID = '" & Me.txtProductID & "'")

txtCommission.Value = MyVar * txtQuantity.Value
```

You'll have to change all the textbox names and field names and such to what you've actually got on your form and table, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it!